# How to append an item index in list in jinja ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts, ansible-template

This is the example  I am working on:

```
{% set server_ip = [] %}
{% for ip in host_ip  %}
{% set _ = server_ip.append('data'+loop.index ) }}
{% endfor %}
{{ server_ip}}
```

I want the output to be [data0 , data1 , data3] in case my host ip has 3 items

Comment: What isn't working as expected when you execute that template and which step did you take to debug ?

Comment: Sorry about my incomplete post, I was able to append only with this .append('data'), so with this I got a list of items named data. but I want the result to be data concatenated with the current index. That didn't work with the example I posted. But now, I tried with .append(''.join('data', loop.index|string)) and it is working

Answer (score 0):

Q: *"**Output to be [data0 , data1 , data2] in case host_ip has 3 items.**"*

A: The task does the job

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        server_ip: "{{ ['data']|
                       product(range(host_ip|length)|list)|
                       map('join')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  server_ip:
  - data0
  - data1
  - data2
```